# Spark submit - AM Container for appattempt_1512628475693_0641_000001 exited with exitCode: 15

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, hortonworks-data-platform

I am running a Spark job in yarn - cluster mode and it is failing with the following error.
could anyone please suggest the reason/ cause for this.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1512628475693_0641 finished with failed status
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1261)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:1307)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:751)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

The diagnostics from Ambari are as following

```
AM Container for appattempt_1512628475693_0641_000001 exited with exitCode: 15 
Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch. 
Container id: container_e9342_1512628475693_0641_01_000001 
Exit code: 15 
Stack trace: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.runtime.ContainerExecutionException: Launch container failed
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, please

Comment: Reported error is generic, to find root cause you need to collect yarn application logs using “yarn logs -applicationId application_1512628475693_0641” command

Comment: I checked the yarn logs and below is the abnormality I observed. "CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver commanded a shutdown". Memory store started and registered with the driver, Block manager initialized and driver commanded a shutdown. Could you suggest any reasons

Comment: Can you update the question with full stacktrace?

Comment: Thank you all, I was able to find the problem reading yarn logs.